# why use BeginInit() with simple BitmapImages?

Tags: wpf, syntax, bitmapimage

I have seen a lot of these on the web:

```
var b = new BitmapImage();
b.BeginInit();
b.UriSource = new Uri(myPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
b.EndInit();
myImage.Source = b;
```

now, as far as I'm concerned, I would first have gone for the more compact version:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(myPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

is there any reason why I should write the first one instead of the second one?

what is it exactly that "BeginInit()" and "EndInit()" do in this case, that would not be done in the second version?

I'm guessing "nothing", but then again, I've had enough experience showing me that WPF is a lot more subtle than I would have thought it is to not wonder...

edit: Just to be clear, my point is NOT that I absolutely want to spare 4 lines of code. I'd rather like to know what those two methods do, exactly, and the reason they should (or should not) be called.

Comment: I ***guess*** there is no problem here because you have a handy constructor which takes the Uri as a parameter. But for other property initializations, where you cannot pass the into any constructor, you'll have to do it the first way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the two methods can only be used in pairs and throw an `InvalidOperationException` tells me that they `stall` the initialization of the `BitmapImage`. Any property initialization between the two methods will be made before the `BitmapImage` is initialized.

And as I said in the comment,

I guess there is no problem here because you have a handy constructor which takes the Uri as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

I think they do this, just to be consistent with other code. BitmapImage have several properties, that have to be set only once before it load the image. For example `DecodePixelHeight` and `DecodePixelWidth`.
In order to set them correctly, you have to use `BeginInit` way. And of course, when someone shows examples, they just use the same syntax they are used to, and only remove lines of unrelated properties.
If you don't need to set any of them, you may brief syntax.